# The Application appear black background area in iOS Simulator & my phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Creating ***iOS application project*** with Xcode 6.4, after ***deleting the main storyboard (and the project.plist)*** and the xxx.xib,the simulator (my phone) appear ***black background area*** at the *top and bottom* of the application window.

**if somebody known this, please tell me why and what should do to resolve this, sincerely  appreciate**! [image: the result of this]

Comment: Splash Screen/Launch Screen is missing. Add Splash Screen/Launch Screen of respective size and check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add launch screen for your app. It will be solved.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html

Comment: resolve problem using Launch Images Source , but why??

Comment: Without Launch Images or Launch Screen nib, likely it will set the app for 3.5 inches

Answer (score 0):

if you are supporting `iOS 7` also then u have to add `Launch Images Source` and for `iOS 8` add `Launch Screen nib` then your problem is solved.

Comment: resolve problem using Launch Images Source , but why??

Comment: The Launch Screen nib is supported for only iOS 8 not for iOS 7.For iOS 7 u have to use Image assets